Absolutely irreducible polynomials over a field are irreducible over any field extension
Let $k$ be a field and let $f\in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ be a polynomial that is irreducible in $\overline k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. (That is, $f$ is absolutely irreducible.) I would like to show that $f$ is irreducible in $K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ for any extension $K/k$. (This is a problem from an old algebra exam.)
The exam provides the following hint:

Suppose $f=gh$ over $K$ with $g,h$ nonconstant. Find a finitely generated $\overline k$-subalgebra $R\subset\overline K$ over which the factorization occurs, and reduce modulo a suitable maximal ideal of $R$.

I have followed the hint, but I am worried I am missing something, since I don't see why we need to pick a "suitable" maximal ideal of $R$—it seems to me that any maximal ideal will do.
Here's my idea: Let $R$ be the $\overline k$-subalgebra generated by the coefficients of $g$ and the coefficients of $h$. Let $M$ be any maximal ideal of $R$, so by Zariski's lemma $R/M\cong \overline k$. Write $\overline f$ for the polynomial obtained by reducing the coefficients of $f$ mod $M$, and likewise for $\overline g$ and $\overline h$. Then, reducing mod $M$, we have $\overline f = \overline g\overline h$. Since the coefficients of $f$ are in $k$, they're units in $R$ (i.e., not in $M$), so in fact $\overline f=f$. And neither $\overline g$ nor $\overline h$ is constant, since otherwise the leading term on the RHS (under some monomial order) would no longer have multidegree equal to that of the leading term of $f$. Hence we have obtained a factorization of $f$ into a product of nonconstant polynomials in $\overline k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, contradiction.
Does this work? Or do I actually have to be more careful to choose a "suitable" maximal ideal $M$ of $R$, and if so, where in this argument do things go wrong if I pick an unsuitable $M$?

I think your proof of $f = \overline{f}$ is not correct. But it can easily be fixed. Be careful, zero is not a unit.

I think one has to be extra careful with the claim that the reductions of $g$ and $h$ are not constant. This is where a specific choice of $M$ might be essential. (I didn't fully grasp your proof at this step.)
